# how to get hours from time stamp

Tags: sql

I want to just get the hours from the timestamp on sql.

[Time stamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbesV.png)

Comment: As per question guidelines, please do not post images. Please tag your rdbms

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP misses to show any effort to search for a solution. This question has been asked many times before and the answer can simply be found using Google and reading documentations or previous questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Please tag your rdbms next time.

For MySQL, you can use [HOUR ( )](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_hour.asp)

For SQL-Server, you can use [DATEPART ( )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16)